# players not moving simultaneously

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am attempting to make a game in python with the turtle module, I have the square moving towards the player (the circle) and the aim is for the circle to jump over the square and not get hit.
The player can jump by pressing the spacebar,
 but every time you hit the space bar to jump the player jumps, but the square stops moving and you are unable to jump over.
here is my code:

```
import turtle
import time

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.title("dinosaur run")
wn.tracer(1,20)    


floor = turtle.Turtle()
floor.fd(370)
floor.bk(370*2)
floor.ht()

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape("circle")
player.penup()
player.setpos(-370,14)

def jump():
    player.lt(90)
    player.fd(40)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    player.bk(40)
    player.rt(90)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(jump, "space")

class cactus(turtle.Turtle):
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.setpos(370,14)
    cactusspeed = 2

while True:
    x = turtle.xcor()
    x -= cactusspeed
    turtle.setx(x)
```

Thanks a lot,
all ideas welcome,
I've tried wn.update() at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided above, your code doesn't run at all as `cactusspeed` never gets defined.  And your `class cactus` doesn't have a hope of working as currently laid out (reread about Python classes.)  Finally, your `while True:` has no business in an event driven world like turtle.

Below is my rework of your code to use an `ontimer()` event to control the cactus independent of the player.  I also eliminated the `sleep()` and simply made the player move slower and jump higher.  I believe this should give you the dynamic you're looking for:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def jump():
    player.forward(100)
    player.backward(100)

def move():
    if cactus.xcor() < -screen.window_width()/2:
        cactus.hideturtle()
        cactus.setx(370)
        cactus.showturtle()
    else:
        cactus.forward(cactusspeed)

    screen.ontimer(move, 40)

screen = Screen()

floor = Turtle(visible=False)
floor.speed('fastest')
floor.fd(370)
floor.bk(370 * 2)

player = Turtle("circle", visible=False)
player.penup()
player.setpos(-370, 14)
player.setheading(90)
player.speed('slowest')
player.showturtle()

cactusspeed = 4

cactus = Turtle("square", visible=False)
cactus.speed('fastest')
cactus.penup()
cactus.setpos(370, 14)
cactus.setheading(180)
cactus.showturtle()

screen.onkey(jump, "space")
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```